# Start app in a web flow

Tags: spring-webflow

I am using spring web flow 2.
I want that my first page to be one of a flow. How can I do that? I tried to set the welcome-file but it doesn't work. 
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Luisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the following index.html in the root of your webapp (next to WEB-INF) according to 'spring booking' test app that goes with Webflow distro:
index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=spring/startFlowName"/>
</head>
</html>
```